# How to simplify variable parameter template functions?

Tags: c++, templates

Recently, I came up with an idea when learning to call function pointers. I used template variable parameters to construct template functions so that I can call function pointers

```
#include<functional>
#include<Windows.h>
template<class T, class ...Args>
decltype(auto) ExecuteFunc(LPVOID f, Args&& ...args) {
    if (f != nullptr) {
        return std::function<T>((T*)f)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }
}
int main(){
ExecuteFunc<int(HWND, char*, char*, int)>(&MessageBoxA, (HWND)NULL, (char*)"Text", (char*)"caption", MB_OK);
return 0;
}
```

Although this code runs well, it seems a bit too long
[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/497Fe.png)
Is there a way to shorten the code?

I hope the code can be simplified to call.

```
ExecuteFunc<int>(&MessageBoxA, (HWND)NULL, (char*)"Text", (char*)"caption", MB_OK);
```

If you have some interesting ideas, please express them freely.

Supplementary description.
Some of the answers misunderstood my question and changed the type of the argument, which apparently std::invoke doesn't do yet.
Argument one is passed in as a function pointer address, not the name of an already exported function
Example 2.

```
LPVOID FunAddr=&MessageBoxA;
int ret=ExecuteFunc<int>(FunAddr, (HWND)NULL, (char*) "Text", (char*) "caption", MB_OK);
```

**int** ret=ExecuteFunc<**int**> means that the **return value of the function is of type int**
FunAddr is the address of a function where you can't directly give the symbolic name of the function the rest of the function's parameters

Also I know that FunAddr doesn't have any available type information, but the parameters given can extract this type information and splice it to **T(int,int)**

```
template<class T,class . .Args>
T ExecuteFunc(LPVOID f, Args&&... .args) {

}
```

Comment: Why is the type of `f` not `T*` but `LPVOID`? Discarding type information usually does not go well with templates. (And why convert to `std::function` before calling it?)

Comment: `MessageBoxA(NULL, "Text", "caption", MB_OK)` would be shorter still. What's the point of the exercise?

Comment: You are probably looking for something like [this](https://godbolt.org/z/7qE9vobKh)

Comment: F is the address of a function, so let's say I pass in the address of msgbox and I give you the type of function to call, in this case msgbox is an exported function, but I'm actually going to use this method to call an unexported function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you to all our friends for your support and comments.
Your enthusiastic comments have provided me with constructive help
At the moment I have accepted a more simple answer, which meets my needs very well.

The code and examples are as follows

```
template<class T,class F, class ...Args>
inline decltype(auto) ExecuteFunc(F f, Args&&...args) {
    return reinterpret_cast<T(*)(Args...)>(f)(args...);
}
```

Example

```
#include<Windows.h>
#include<iostream>
template<class T, class F, class ...Args>
inline decltype(auto) ExecuteFunc(F f, Args&&...args) {
    return reinterpret_cast<T(*)(Args...)>(f)(args...);
}
int Add(int a, int b) {
    return a + b;
}

int main(){
    //1.
    LPVOID funcptr = &Add;
    std::cout << ExecuteFunc<int>(funcptr, 1, 2) << std::endl;
    //2.
    std::cout << ExecuteFunc<int>(Add, 3, 5) << std::endl;
    //3.
    ExecuteFunc<int>(MessageBoxA,(HWND)NULL, (char*)"Text", (char*)"caption", MB_OK);
    return 0;
}
```

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DgpL5.png)

Answer (score 1):

There's an issue with the implementation of `ExecuteFunc`: It doesn't return a value on every path which is undefined behaviour.

To me this looks like you're trying to reinvent [`std::invoke`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/invoke) though. `std::invoke` can do anything other than execute the null check for you.

```
std::invoke(&MessageBoxA, nullptr, "Text", "caption", MB_OK);
```

If you really want to implement this yourself, you could be using something like this:

```
template<class F, class ...Args>
decltype(auto) ExecuteFunc(F&& f, Args&&...args)
{
    if constexpr (std::is_pointer_v<F>)
    {
        using ResultType = decltype(std::declval<F>()(std::forward<Args>(args)...));

        if (f == nullptr)
        {
            // return the default constructed return value, if a null function pointer is passed
            return ResultType{};
        }
    }
    return std::forward<F>(f)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

int AddOne(int i)
{
    return i + 1;
}

int main()
{
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(ExecuteFunc(&MessageBoxA, nullptr, "Text", "caption", MB_OK)), int>); // just to show the return type is as expected for MessageBoxA
    std::cout << ExecuteFunc(&AddOne, 5) << '\n';
    std::cout << ExecuteFunc(static_cast<decltype(&AddOne)>(nullptr), 5) << '\n';
    std::cout << ExecuteFunc([](int i) {return i + 1; }, 5) << '\n';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<functional>
#include<Windows.h>
template<class T, class ...Args>
decltype(auto) ExecuteFunc(T f, Args&& ...args) {
    f(args...);
}

int main() {
    ExecuteFunc(std::function{ MessageBoxA }, (HWND)NULL, (char*)"Text", (char*)"caption", MB_OK);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).